# Achieving very poor fps for my iphone app for decode + display h264 frames using ffmpeg and opengl

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ffmpeg, h.264

I have three steps process for my application which display h264 frame on iPhone screen.

1. decode using ffmpeg.
2. scale and colorspace conversion (scale to 256 X 256 Opengl ES 1 texture and convert colospace from yuv420p to rgb565 using sws_Scale from ffmpeg).
3. Render opengl 1 texture to frame buffer to render buffer

after these three step process, I got my picture on iPhone screen.

When I was testing the performance for 720 X 576 resolution frames, I obtain very poor FPS. It is reaching max to 180 milliseconds and hence resulting into 5 to 6 FPS.

Any direction will be grateful.

Comment: Is this from an H.264 movie file that AVAssetReader can read, or do you absolutely have to use FFmpeg?

Comment: I am downloading h264 compressed frame from a tcp connection and forward it for decode + display process. I am not using AVAsseReader. I need to use ffmpeg for decoding as I didn't find any alternate decoder to decode h264 frame by frame.